# Strange border on PNG images in pdf

Tags: graphics, pdf, png, powerpoint

I make figures in powerpoint, export them as pngs, and include them in my document. I sometimes get strange borders around them, sometimes around indivual elements of the ppt file, like this (black boxes are just censoring): 
[image: pic]

It doesn't print, but looks bad on the screen. Any tips to get rid of it?

Comment: Water is going upwards in your flow. Powerpoint is not the strongest graphics design software around.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not expert and I wanted to use something user friendly for image layout.

Comment: I had a similar problem and it was caused by a transparent, 1 pixel wide border around the image. In the PDF, it rendered Gray. Therefore, it could be helpful to have a closer look at the exported images. Is there a similar border?

Comment: Following Chris his advice, what you most likely did is turn the border of the elements transparent instead of removing the borders. Although there is no visual difference in powerpoint, things can get messed up in PDF conversion.